Flink Conditional DynamoDB sink
I am looking for an option to select the target DynamoDB table based on the record I receive. From stream of records, is it possible to choose the specific DynamoDB table from pool of 30 tables? It looks like its possible for Kafka sink or s3 buckets. Is there any similar approach or workaround to achieve that using available DynamoDB sink?
